# How to run npm or angular 2 ng serve command from Bash Script?

Tags: linux, bash, angular, scripting

I am looking to create an interactive bash script for our development team (never did this before) as our project has various needs and due to future growth on the team I want this to be easy as pi.

Normally for my work on the team I would change directory to the angular folder and run `ng serve` which kicks off the frontend development server. How do I do that in a bash script?

So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Hello, "$USER".\nWelcome to the BICE build script!\nVersion 0.1"
echo -e "Which build option do you wish to use?\n1. Frontend (default)\n2. Backend\n3. Database\n4. Production"
echo -n "Enter your choice [1-4] or press [ENTER]:"
read choice
if [choice == 1]; then
  echo "Option 1 selected"
  cd /angular
  #call ng serve
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/angular` seems weird as a working directory but if `angular` is a subdirectory of the one holding the script a

```
cd ./angular
ng serve
cd ..
```

should work...

Maybe you could look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within) so you can call the script from any working directory.

Also note that you are missing a `fi` at the end of your `if`,  there sould be spaces after opening and before closing bracket and `choice` should be referenced with a `$` sign:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Hello, "$USER".\nWelcome to the BICE build script!\nVersion 0.1"
echo -e "Which build option do you wish to use?\n1. Frontend (default)\n2. Backend\n3. Database\n4. Production"
echo -n "Enter your choice [1-4] or press [ENTER]:"
read choice
if [ $choice == 1 ]; then
  echo "Option 1 selected"
  cd ./angular
  ng serve
  cd ..
fi
```

Comment: When I do the above (my first thoughts too) I get syntax error: unexpected end of file. That got me thinking that it tried but couldn't so reached EOF and died.

Comment: This is so cool! Thanks for the help I can probably muddle my way through now and using the documentation.